# In Mongoose/MongoDB, how to update properties in an array of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following model:

An order model:

```
var order = new Schema({
content: [{
    product: {type: String, required: true},
    quantity: {type: Number},
    vatRate: {type: Number, required: true},
    price: {type: Number},
    deviceId: {type: String}
    }],
number: {type: Number},
tableId: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Table'}
isAutomated: {type: Boolean, default: true},
createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

A table model:

```
var table = {
tableNumber: {type: Number, default: 0},
status: {type: String, enum: ['Booked', 'Free', 'Active'], default: 'Free'},
order: [order]
};
```

A device model:

```
var device = {
    deviceId: {type: String, required: true},
    status: {type: String, enum: ['Booked', 'Free', 'Active'], default:   'Free'},
    token: {type: String},
    tableId: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Table'},
    isEnabled: {type: Boolean, default: true}
};
```

A client model:

```
var client = new Schema({
    information: {
        code: {type: String, required: true},
        name: {type: String, required: true}
},
account: {
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    token: {type: String}
},
devices: [device],
tables: [table],
products: [product],
notifications: [notification],
createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

A client has multiple tables.
A table has multiple orders.

How can I update an order which is in an array of orders and itself is in an array of tables ?

In another part of my code, I know how to do it when there is only one level of array...like that:

```
 clientModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        "information.code": clientCode,
        'devices.deviceId': deviceId
    },
    {
        $set: {
            'devices.$.status': device.status,
            'devices.$.tableId': device.tableId
        }
    },
    {
        new: true,
        select: {
            devices: {
                $elemMatch: {deviceId: deviceId}
            }
        }
    },
```

But how to do it with nested arrays ??

Thanks for your help,

Patrice

Answer (score 2):

Use $push operator to update array entries. Nested arrays can be accessed using the '.' notation as explained [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)